# Error when executing MSCK REPAIR TABLE sentence

Tags: apache-spark, hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am trying to execute the statement:

`spark.sql(f"MSCK REPAIR TABLE schema.table_1")`

And get the following error:

*org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: InvalidObjectException(message:Payload size of request exceeded limit. (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException...*

It seems that the table is too large or has too many partitions and exceeds the limit that Hive has to do this operation.

I have tried to set this configuration to do this task in batches, but have not been successful:

`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.hive.msck.repair.batch.size", "20")`